# XCode 5 multiline @param comment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comments

I was wondering if it's possible to create a multiline comment for a @param. Here's what i mean:

```
/**
 * Some description
 *
 * @param test Some test parameter
               this should start on a new line
               this as well
 */
```

The above code puts all three lines in one.
Now the only way i know to start something with a new line is to have an empty line before like so:

```
/**
 * Some description
 *
 * @param test Some test parameter

               this should start on a new line

               this as well
 */
```

Unfortunately, the above code thinks that the last two lines belong to description rather than the @param. Is there any way to let xcode know that this description is still for @param ?

Comment: What do you mean by `let xcode know`?  Xcode only parses the first couple continuous lines of text documenting methods.  Because your @param begins after a break, Xcode won't generate headerdoc for it.

Comment: @CodaFi xcode parses the entire code block and the "param" successfully shows up in quick help. In fact, there's quite a lot of things you can do with the new comment syntaxes.